# How to resize header inside NavigationLink view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am currently trying to resize the top of the view when a NavigationLink is opened. As you can see from my screenshot, it's somehow double and there is a line separating the header. Do you know how I could get rid of the part above the back arrow?

[Screenshot View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tsoS.png)

This is my code

```
NavigationView{
            List(presenter.sections, id: \.self) { section in
                Section(header: Text(section.title)) {
                    ForEach(section.items, id: \.self) { item in
                        NavigationLink("\(item.selectModel.title) \(item.selectModel.selectedValue?.name ?? "")") {
                            List{
                                ForEach(selectModel.listSelection, id: \.self) { value in
                                    Button(action: {selectModel.action(value)}) {
                                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                            Text(value.name)
                                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        }
                                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                                        .cornerRadius(12)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .offset(y: 50)
                        }
                        .navigationBarTitle(selectModel.title, displayMode: .inline)
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("TEST", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
```

Comment: Don't you use **second** navigation view in link destination?

Comment: Do you mean I should wrap everything that comes after the NavigationLink in another NavigationView?

Comment: No, opposite to that - there should be only one NavigationView. Extra space might be due to used two (or more) NavigationView(s) on stack.